# Dotnet Core NuGet package dependency build issue on Azure DevOps

Tags: .net-core, nuget, azure-devops

With no changes at all to source code or pipelines, I am now experiencing an issue where none of my build pipelines work anymore in Azure DevOps. The package that is being referenced isn't a dependency for this project, nor has it ever been. I can't work out what's causing this or how I can go about troubleshooting.

```
2018-11-26T10:25:14.2812751Z Restoring packages for C:\Agent\_work\19\s\OrchestrateIT.Web\OrchestrateIT.csproj...
2018-11-26T10:25:14.7577515Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.400\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://orchestrate-it.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Shared_DBUpdate/nuget/v3/index.json. [C:\Agent\_work\19\s\OrchestrateIT.DataImportScheduler\OrchestrateIT.DataImportScheduler.csproj]
2018-11-26T10:25:14.7577910Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.400\NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [C:\Agent\_work\19\s\OrchestrateIT.DataImportScheduler\OrchestrateIT.DataImportScheduler.csproj]
2018-11-26T10:25:14.7579439Z     0 Warning(s)
2018-11-26T10:25:14.7579628Z     1 Error(s)
2018-11-26T10:25:14.7579743Z 
2018-11-26T10:25:14.7579902Z Time Elapsed 00:00:02.18
2018-11-26T10:25:14.7906687Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1
```

Local (manual) build works fine. I have already tried clearing Nuget cache and VSTS agent cache. A quick workaround might be to solve the authorisation issue (even though the package isn't required) however I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Even though my Personal Access Token had not expired, for some reason I needed to remove and add this package back to my sources with the same PAT. This resolved the authentication issue and therefore resolved the build issue.

It is still unclear to me as to why this package is being considered as a dependency for this project though.

Comment: Can u please tell how u cleared Nuget cache and VSTS agent cache as u mentioned.